# Calculate total time in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i have same problem like here

> [how to calculate sum time with data type char in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579152/how-to-calculate-sum-time-with-data-type-char-in-oracle)

but little different. i have 2 table like this :

```
table employee

emp_id   emp_name   emp_birth_date

123456   sacha      18/07/1980
```

Using this query

```
create table employee (emp_id char(10), emp_name char(10), emp_birth_date date);
insert into employee values ('123456', 'sacha', (TO_DATE('18/07/1980', 'dd/mm/yyyy')));
```

and table dept

```
table dept

emp_id    emp_reg_date   emp_time_in    emp_time_off

123456    25/12/2011     10:00:00       19:00:00
```

using this query

```
create table dept (emp_id char(10), emp_reg_date date, emp_time_in char(10), emp_time_off char(10));
insert into dept values ('123456', (TO_DATE('25/12/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy')), '10:00:00', '19:00');
```

all data type is char except birth_date and reg_date

i can display emp_id, emp_name, emp_reg_date, emp_time_in, emp_time_off using this query `select employee.emp_id, employee.emp_name, dept.emp_date_reg, dept.emp_time_in, dept.emp_time_off from employee, dept where employee.emp_id = dept.emp_id;`

but how to calculate total time in table dept for emp_time_in and emp_time_off for a day and a month?

Comment: How do you record an employee who started a night shift at 22:00 on January 31 and came out at 06:00 the next morning, on February 1? If you only store one date, it's perhaps January 31 in this example. But what do you do, then, with shifts that are more than 24 hours (as, for example, for airline pilots, or medical residents)? Change the data model as soon as possible!

Comment: @mathguy yes, you are right, i just get data model like that from the task. Thank you for your advice :) i will learn it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What an awful design; what made you create EMP_TIME_IN and EMP_TIME_OFF VARCHAR2 columns? Those should have been DATE ones. I suggest you change that.

Meanwhile, you'll have to concatenate EMP_REG_DATE and those IN and OFF columns in order to get DATE value; then, by subtracting two dates, you'd get number of DAYS and - using a little bit of mathematics - get hours, minutes, or whatever you want.

For example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (empno        number,
  3     emp_reg_date date,
  4     emp_time_in  varchar2(10),
  5     emp_time_off varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, date '2018-03-20', '10:00', '19:00');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, date '2018-03-21', '11:30', '12:30');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (2, date '2018-03-25', '13:00', '16:20');

1 row created.
```

Employee 1 worked 9 hours + 1 hour = 10 hours in total.
Employee 2 worked 3 hours 20 minutes.

```
SQL> with dates as
  2    (select
  3       empno,
  4       to_date(to_char(emp_reg_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || emp_time_in , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') date_in,
  5       to_date(to_char(emp_reg_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || emp_time_off, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') date_off
  6     from test
  7    ),
  8  summary as
  9    (select empno,
 10       sum(date_off - date_in) diff_days
 11     from dates
 12     group by empno
 13    )
 14  select empno,
 15    trunc(diff_days * 24) hours,
 16    round((diff_days * 24 - trunc(diff_days * 24)) * 60) minutes
 17  from summary;

     EMPNO      HOURS    MINUTES
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10          0
         2          3         20

SQL>
```

Note that there's practically no control over what you enter into VARCHAR2 columns TIME_IN and TIME_OUT; what prevents you from entering AX:FM or 99:45 or A-b-e_XF in there? All those are valid strings, but invalid times.

Once again: fix data model.

Comment: perfect! Thanks for your help i really appreciate it :) and i will learn it again

Comment: You're welcome; but seriously, change those column's datatype.